# Autoit Why is (0 <> "Test") False

Tags: autoit, logical-operators

I am fetching a numeric value from an HTML table. If it fails to fetch the value I fill the value "NA" instead. Here is the odd part 0 <> "NA" is false, 0 = "NA" is true, 0 == "NA" is False. I get that = is not case sensitive, and == is, but I thought <> was case sensitive... So why does it work like this?

```
Local $x = 0
If $x <> "Test" Then
    MsgBox(0,"","x <> Test")
Else
    MsgBox(0,"","x = Test")
EndIf
```

With this exaplle I get a message box "x = Test"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but I thought `<>` was case sensitive

According to [the docs](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_operators.htm), it is not a string-specific comparison operator like `==`. Rather, it’s just the negation of `=`, so your string will still be interpreted as an integer – both `"NA"` and `"Test"` becoming `0` – and fail to satisfy `0 <> 0`.

> Tests if two values are not equal. **Case insensitive** when used with strings. To do a case sensitive not equal comparison use `Not ("string1" == "string2")`